# Pyparsing reading unicode characters from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pyparsing

I'd like to read some values from sample.cfg file and parse them. The code looks like this :

```
from pyparsing import *

key = Word(alphanums)('key')
equals = Suppress('=')
value = Word(alphanums)('value')

kvexpression = key + equals + value

with open('sample.cfg') as config_in:
  config_data = config_in.read()

for match in kvexpression.scanString(config_data):
  result = match[0]
  print("{0} is {1}".format(result.key, result.value))
```

If I use ASCII characters it works fine. Like this :

**sample.cfg**

```
city=Atlanta
state=Georgia
population=5522942
```

But if I use some unicode characters in the input file. It doesn't works as expected.

**sample.cfg (with unicode letters)**

```
şehir=İzmir
ülke=Türkiye
nüfus=4279677
```

If you run this program its output is like this:

```
lke is T
fus is 4279677
```

As you'd see it ignores unicode characters.

**Update :**

I altered the code as suggested. Now it became like this :

```
from pyparsing import*

key = Word(alphanums + alphas8bit)('key')
equals = Suppress('=')
value = Word(alphanums + alphas8bit)('value')

kvexpression = key + equals + value

with open('şehir.cfg') as config_in:
  config_data = config_in.read()

for match in kvexpression.scanString(config_data):
  result = match[0]
  print("{0} is {1}".format(result.key, result.value))
```

And minor changes in data file :

**sample.cfg**

```
şehir=İzmir
ülke=Türkiye
nüfus=4279677
alfabe=AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGgĞğHhIiİiJjKkLlMmNnOoÖöPpRrSsŞşTtUuÜüVvYyZz
```

When I run the program it's output is like this.

```
ülke is Türkiye
nüfus is 4279677
alfabe is AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGg
```

As you'd see the first line which starts with accented s 'ş' is not displayed. I noticed this situation before.

Almost there, yet not quite.

I use a linux box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've find a solution by my self. I don't know whether it is the convenient way to achieve this. But it looks fine to me.

from pyparsing import*

```
alphanums_tr = u'abcçdefgğhiijklmnoöprsştuüvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ0123456789'

key = Word(alphanums_tr)('key')
equals = Suppress('=')
value = Word(alphanums_tr)('value')

kvexpression = key + equals + value

with open('şehir.cfg') as config_in:
  config_data = config_in.read()

for match in kvexpression.scanString(config_data):
    result = match[0]
    print("{0} is {1}".format(result.key, result.value))
```

Program's output is like this :

```
şehir is İzmir
ülke is Türkiye
nüfus is 4279677
alfabe is AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGgĞğHhIiİiJjKkLlMmNnOoÖöPpRrSsŞşTtUuÜüVvYyZz
```

Comment: Try the new `pyparsing.pyparsing_unicode.Latin1.alphanums` in pyparsing version 2.3.0

Comment: If an additional range is needed for the LatinA and LatinB extensions, this is easily done. I see that I also omitted docstrings for these ranges, which would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `alphanums` with `alphanums+alphas8bit` in two places in your code, as in this line.

```
key = Word(alphanums+alphas8bit)('key')
```

The problem is that `alphanums` matches only the unaccented Latin alphabet (plus the numerical digits). `alphas8bit` matches the additional 8-bit characters in Latin-1.

When I run the altered code against this input,

```
sehir=Izmir
ülke=Türkiye
nüfus=4279677
AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGgGgHhIiIiJjKkLlMmNnOoÖöPpRrSsSsTtUuÜüVvYyZz = 5
```

where the entire Turkish alphabet appears in the last line, the result is,

```
sehir is Izmir
ülke is Türkiye
nüfus is 4279677
AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGgGgHhIiIiJjKkLlMmNnOoÖöPpRrSsSsTtUuÜüVvYyZz is 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. But it doesn't displays the first line. I've updated the post to show the changes.

Comment: Apologies, @Erdem! I don't know how I missed that flaw in my result. Good that you got a result anyway.

Comment: Try the new `pyparsing.pyparsing_unicode.Latin1.alphanums` in pyparsing version 2.3.0